# Equivalent of onbeforescriptexecute in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent of the onbeforescriptexecute or beforescript execute event in Chrome? I would like to intercept and print out the javascript code that is being executed before any javascript on the page is loaded. This should include Javascript within script tags and other attributes like onblur, etc. 
Thanks

Comment: You could maybe achieve it with defer and or async see this http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/ article which explain their use and why we have them

Answer (score 7):

Here is a polyfill of `onbeforescriptexecute` event: https://gist.github.com/jspenguin2017/cd568a50128c71e515738413cd09a890

It works on Chrome and Edge, but ironically not on Firefox.

To print the script content, just do `console.log(e.script.textContent);` inside the event handler. You can call `e.replacePayload(payload);` to change the script to run, or `e.preventDefault()` to block the script.

`e.preventDefault();` takes precedence over `e.replacePayload(...);`, if `e.replacePayload(...);` is called multiple times, the last call will override all previous calls. You can call `e.stopPropagation();` to ensure your new payload gets registered.

Unfortunately, `textContent` does not always work properly for huge scripts. It should be fine for debugging. Also, it only works for "hard coded" inline scripts, not those dynamically injected from other scripts. You can still monitor those scripts, but you can't interfere with their execution.

It's a bit tricky for `onblur`, you might have to use a custom observer that scans for it.

Comment: I'm going to remove my upvote just so I can upvote this a second time.  With your polyfill I was able to use Tampermonkey to remove an auto log-out nag and fetch the server-side keepalive on a setInterval.  I did have to replace all the `window` objects with `unsafeWindow` and add `@grant unsafeWindow` to my script headers.

Comment: Now at https://github.com/jspenguin2017/Snippets/blob/master/onbeforescriptexecute.html

Comment: It should be mentioned that this method works only for inline scripts. That is, it doesn't work if the script is loaded as a resource by using "src" tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only for Firefox :( Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

#### A really bad advice:

Well, by default scripts are loaded in a sync (with space, as opposed to `async`) way.
So, you can access the latest loaded script tag looking for last existing `<script>` tag in head (which is almost exactly the opposite thing of what you're trying to achieve.

I'll be glad to see any other answer (probably a much better one) to your question, but it the whole idea of using that kind of behaviour looks bad to me.

#### A slightly better one

Usually, to do something like that you should load scripts via ajax and handle them before they're added to DOM and executed.

The best solution in my opinion would be using asynchronous modules with AMD loaders such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) this should keep your code more organized.

I do realize it doesn't solve your problem, but hopefully I helped yo a little bit :)